# Using Scala classes as DTOs in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, scala, spring-mvc

In my project I'm using Spring + Scala.

Some of my Spring MVC controllers uses Spring feature for binding incoming HTTP parameters to DTO object. Like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = Array("/", ""), method = Array(RequestMethod.POST))
    def saveProduct(dto: MyDto): Iterable[MyDto] = {...}
```

And `MyDto` is simple scala class:

```
class MyDto extends Serializable {
   @BeanProperty var id : Long = _
   @BeanProperty var name: String  = _
}
```

My problem is that I'm getting exceptions when  trying to use Scala `Option` class for fields in `MyDto`:

```
class MyDto extends Serializable {
   @BeanProperty var id : Option[Long] = None
   @BeanProperty var name: Option[String]  = None
}
```

Exception message is:

`Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'scala.Option' for property 'name';`

What I can do to use Scala Options as type if fields in `MyDto`?

Comment: It might get a bit complicated, but you'll need to [register a custom `PropertyEditor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion-customeditor-registration) to handle class `Option[T]`. The problem may well be getting it to correctly handle the parameterized type `T` :-(

Answer (score 4):

I am not a Scala expert, but here is one way:

Create a converter, along these lines:

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter

class TypeToOptionOfTypeConverter[T] extends Converter[T, Option[T]] {
  override def convert(source: T): Option[T] = {
    Some(source)
  }
}
```

Register this converter with Spring MVC:

```
class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  override def addFormatters(registry: FormatterRegistry): Unit = {
    registry.addConverter(classOf[String], classOf[Option[String]], new TypeToOptionOfTypeConverter[String])
    registry.addConverter(classOf[Long], classOf[Option[Long]], new TypeToOptionOfTypeConverter[Long])
  }
}
```

That should be it, now your DTO should get cleanly mapped.

Comment: Is it possible not to register all possible types which can be used with `Option`? If new type will be added, then I will need to register one more converter. I think registering all possible types in not clear

Comment: Because of type erasure it appears to work for any option. I tried this `registry.addConverter(classOf[Any], classOf[Option[Any]], new TypeToOptionOfTypeConverter[Any])` and it appears to handle all Option conversions

Answer (score 0):

Spring has support for converting types using converters with its data binding. You will need to implement the converter so that Spring knows how to convert, for example, String to Option[String].

See:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert